# Advantages of using sqlalchemy.types over sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

When saving to a SQL Server database using SQLAlchemy are there advantages to setting datatypes using `sqlalchemy.types` over `sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql` besides portability?

I'm saving data to a database using the following (making use of pandas' `to_sql()`):

```
df_members.to_sql(
    'parliament.member_' + extract_date + '',
    schema='source',
    con=engine,
    index=False,
    dtype={
        'id': sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.SMALLINT(),
        'gender': sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.NVARCHAR(1),
        'nameDisplayAs': sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.NVARCHAR(length=256),
        'nameClean': sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.NVARCHAR(length=256),
        'count': sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.TINYINT()
    },
)
```

I note that the following yields the same results:

```
df_members.to_sql(
    'parliament.member_' + extract_date + '',
    schema='source',
    con=engine,
    index=False,
    dtype={
        'id': sqlalchemy.types.SMALLINT(),
        'gender': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(1),
        'nameDisplayAs': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=256),
        'nameClean': sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=256),
        'count': sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.TINYINT()
    },
)
```

I've got in the habit of using the former because it saves me having to remember which datatypes are vendor-specific (e.g. `TINYINT()`) and which aren't.

But, assuming portability isn't a concern (if we ever changed vendor the code would need updating anyway to remove the `TINYINT()` references) are there disadvantages to this approach - for example, speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this answer to your question but using the source code:

In [sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/**init**.py](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/77357be824095b46eb2ed3206bc555a6dacc7f30/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/__init__.py#L34):

```
from .base import SMALLINT
```

In [sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/77357be824095b46eb2ed3206bc555a6dacc7f30/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mssql/base.py#L968)

```
from ...types import SMALLINT
```

In [sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/types.py](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/77357be824095b46eb2ed3206bc555a6dacc7f30/lib/sqlalchemy/types.py#L54)  **<<< sqlalchemy.types.SMALLINT**

```
from .sql.sqltypes import SMALLINT as SMALLINT
```

Go further

In [sqlalchemy/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/77357be824095b46eb2ed3206bc555a6dacc7f30/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py#L3308-L3318)

```
class SMALLINT(SmallInteger):
    """The SQL SMALLINT type.
    .. seealso::

        :class:`_types.SmallInteger` - documentation for the base type.
    """
    __visit_name__ = "SMALLINT"
```

So for many (all?) UPPERCASE types, using `sqlalchemy.types.XXX` or `sqlalchemy.dialects.YYY.XXX` seems to be the same thing. All UPPERCASE datatypes are inherited from CamelCase datatypes ([ref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#the-uppercase-datatypes))